# Adding records to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, invoice

I am working with invoice data that looks like this (2 records):

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Line>
  <SupplierID>Waltons</SupplierID>
  <InvoiceID>MOD280229SI</InvoiceID>
  <InvoiceDate>20120709</InvoiceDate>
  <ItemID>847308</ItemID>
  <ColorID>04</ColorID>
  <Description>BANTEX Quotation Folder A4 3420</Description>
  <MainCategory>FILES FILING</MainCategory>
  <SubCategory>Quotation Folders</SubCategory>
  <LineNum>17.0000000</LineNum>
  <Qty>30.0000000</Qty>
  <UnitPriceExclTax>19.2500000</UnitPriceExclTax>
  <LineTax>80.8500000</LineTax>
  <LinePriceExclTax>577.5000000</LinePriceExclTax>
  <ColorName>Blue</ColorName>
  <UOM>Ea</UOM>
  <Backorder>0.0000000</Backorder>
  <INVENTTRANSID>MOD2923560_060</INVENTTRANSID>
</Line>
<Line>
  <SupplierID>Waltons</SupplierID>
  <InvoiceID>MOD280229SI</InvoiceID>
  <InvoiceDate>20120709</InvoiceDate>
  <ItemID>847308</ItemID>
  <ColorID>06</ColorID>
  <Description>BANTEX Quotation Folder A4 3420</Description>
  <MainCategory>FILES FILING</MainCategory>
  <SubCategory>Quotation Folders</SubCategory>
  <LineNum>18.0000000</LineNum>
```

Keeping the above structure in mind, an order could consist of hundreds of these lines.

I am printing these to invoice pages, and only 18 lines can fit on a page, my overflow rules on the page are already working for that.

My only problem is, I need to print the 1st 17 on the 1st page, then the words balance carried forward, then on the next page start with balance brought forward etc.

I would like to structure the XML as follows

the 1st 16 lines are not altered
After line 16 I want to insert a new line with just Balance Carried Forward
After that I want to insert another blank line totaling at 17 lines (I want to intentionally leave the last line blank)
After the blank line insert another line containing Balance Brought Forward
After this line my data can continue, from line 17+ then after another 15 lines, do the same etc until the end of the data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on building something like this?

I can do this is XSLT 1 or 2 or possibly even do it in JavaScript of VBS.

I have control over the structure of the XML, I am outputting it as a flat file without any sub elements as I 1st need to make some small changes, then I merge this with the rest of my XML file so lets say the XML starts with  and ends with

By line I mean a record, so the above XML has 2 lines (incomplete 2nd line due to copying error) By inserting another line, I mean I would like to add a complete new  XXX  element

Ok imagine I start with XML which consists of 40 lines (elements)

```
<Line>
xxx
</Line>  x40
```

What I want out is as follows:

```
<Line> <!-- x16 lines. from data -->
xxx
</Line> 
<Line> - <!-- Inserted -->
<LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line> - <!-- Inserted -->
<Line></Line>
<Line> - <!-- Inserted -->
<LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line> <!-- x15 lines. From data -->
xxx
</Line>
<Line> <!-- Inserted -->
<LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line> <!-- Inserted -->
<Line></Line>
<Line> <!-- Inserted -->
<LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line> <!-- x9 lines. from data -->
xxx
</Line>
```

Comment: Please state clearly whether the input is a well-formed XML document (where one root element contains all other elements) or a fragment with multiple top level elements as you have posted. And then if you want to use XSLT please explain or show the output format you want, currently I am confused whether your use of the term "line" relates to the `Line` elements in the XML fragment or simply means lines of text.

Comment: Also, please note, that the provided XML is severely malformed: No single top element, non-closed second line element (which also seems truncated). You must show us the exact wanted output from the transformation.

Comment: I have control over the structure of the XML, I am outputting it as a flat file without any sub elements as I 1st need to make some small changes, then I merge this with the rest of my XML file so lets say the XML starts with <Line> and ends with </Line>

Comment: By line I mean a record, so the above XML has 2 lines (incomplete 2nd line due to copying error)

By inserting another line, I mean I would like to add a complete new <Line>
XXX
</Line>
element

Comment: On some platforms like .NET the input to an XSLT transformation can be a fragment without a root element like you posted and it is also possible with XSLT to output a fragment. I am however so far not sure what kind of result you want for your input, consider to show us an input sample and the corresponding result sample you want. I guess for solving the problem the number of elements you want to a new elements after can be a parameter so to allow us to understand your requirement easily simply consider to provide samples where the addition/insertion is done after e.g. 3 elements.

Comment: Ok imagine I start with XML which consists of 30 lines (elements)

<Line>
xxx
</Line>
X30

What I want out is as follows:

(For formatting reasons I will edit the question)

Comment: Do you want to literally include the element contents `Balance Carried Forward` or do you want to compute some value based on the input in the previous `Line` elements?

Comment: Literally insert them. Because of the position of the data, in my design the words will show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion on how to solve that with XslCompiledTransform in the .NET framework, you can read in your XML fragment with an XmlReader with ConformanceLevel.Fragment, then you can process the input with an XSLT like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:param name="size1" select="16"/>

  <xsl:param name="size2" select="15"/>

  <xsl:param name="to-be-inserted">
    <Line>
      <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
    </Line>
    <Line></Line>
    <Line>
      <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
    </Line>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Line[position() &lt;= $size1]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Line[position() &gt; $size1][position() mod $size2 = 1]" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line" mode="group">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$to-be-inserted"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::Line[position() &lt; $size2]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To run that stylesheet with an input file that is not a well-formed XML document you need code like the following:

```
        string sampleInput = @"input1.xml";


        string sampleResult = @"result1.xml";

        XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
        proc.Load("sheet.xslt");

        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sampleInput, new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(sampleResult))
            {
                proc.Transform(xr, null, fs);
            }
        }
```

Assuming you have an input file like

```
<Line>
  <Id>1</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>2</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>3</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>4</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>5</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>6</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>7</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>8</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>9</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>10</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>11</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>12</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>13</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>14</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>15</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>16</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>17</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>18</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>19</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>20</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>21</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>22</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>23</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>24</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>25</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>26</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>27</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>28</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>29</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>30</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>31</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>32</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>33</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>34</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>35</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>36</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>37</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>38</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>39</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>40</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>41</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>42</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>43</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>44</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>45</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>46</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>47</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>48</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>49</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>50</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>51</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>52</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>53</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>54</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>55</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>56</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>57</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>58</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>59</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>60</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>61</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>62</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>63</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>64</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>65</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>66</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>67</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>68</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>69</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>70</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>71</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>72</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>73</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>74</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>75</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>76</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>77</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>78</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>79</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>80</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>81</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>82</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>83</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>84</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>85</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>86</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>87</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>88</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>89</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>90</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>91</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>92</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>93</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>94</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>95</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>96</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>97</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>98</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>99</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>100</Id>
</Line>
```

I get a result like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Line>
  <Id>1</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>2</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>3</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>4</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>5</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>6</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>7</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>8</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>9</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>10</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>11</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>12</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>13</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>14</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>15</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>16</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line />
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>17</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>18</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>19</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>20</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>21</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>22</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>23</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>24</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>25</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>26</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>27</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>28</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>29</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>30</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>31</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line />
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>32</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>33</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>34</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>35</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>36</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>37</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>38</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>39</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>40</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>41</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>42</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>43</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>44</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>45</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>46</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line />
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>47</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>48</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>49</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>50</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>51</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>52</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>53</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>54</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>55</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>56</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>57</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>58</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>59</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>60</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>61</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line />
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>62</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>63</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>64</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>65</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>66</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>67</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>68</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>69</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>70</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>71</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>72</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>73</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>74</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>75</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>76</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line />
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>77</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>78</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>79</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>80</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>81</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>82</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>83</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>84</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>85</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>86</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>87</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>88</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>89</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>90</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>91</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Carried Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line />
<Line>
  <LinePriceExclTax>Balance Brought Forward</LinePriceExclTax>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>92</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>93</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>94</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>95</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>96</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>97</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>98</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>99</Id>
</Line>
<Line>
  <Id>100</Id>
</Line>
```

The number of `Line` elements after which you want to insert new elements and the contents to be inserted are parameters of the stylesheet so you can either edit the stylesheet or even set them with code (by passing in an `XsltArgumentList` as the second argument of the `Transform` method).

Comment: That looks like exactly the answer I was looking for, I will try this in the morning and report back.

Thanks!